# How to start Apache and MySQL automatically when Windows 8 comes up

Tags: apache, xampp

I am using XAMPP, version 3.2.1. I just installed it on Windows 8. Every time I need to go to the XAMPP Control Panel to start services (MySQL, Apache,...); in Windows 7 it started automatically when Windows came up.

Is there a way I can make it auto-start in Windows 8 too?

Comment: Why did you delete the answer? It solved my problem! I was about to mark it as "Solved"; but you deleted it! Thanks anyway :)

Comment: For other people who may reach this topic by Search engines: On XAMPPControl Panel : top right corner: check Apache,MySQL,.. to auto start :)

Comment: @user385729 Trouble is you have to open the control panel before they start. ;)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Start the control panel using "**Run as administrator**". Then you can install Apache and MySQL as a service:

[image]

Comment: You also need to stop the module you want to install as a service then click the "Service" check-box on the left and answer "yes" to the message that pops-up. Unfortunately it doesn't work for Filezilla for some reason.

Comment: I think xampp should have a dialog/hint box that shows up when you try and click Service when it's not run in Administrator, that it is require just so it can inform people.

Comment: There should be a greyed-out button when not in admin mode and a tooltip "run XAMPP as administrator to use". XAMPP people get some UX guys.

Comment: Looks like they changed something. Had to edit the xampp-control.ini file and set values to 1 to be able to this.
[EnableServices]
Apache=1
MySQL=1

Comment: Solution is from KoalaBear as I was having the same problem running as admin, and now you have to manually enable service in config !

Comment: I am sorry to have to downvote this reply. But justifiably so:
It's really amazing that some people answer w/o having fully read the questions (or ignoring key words in them, on purpose just to reply?)  ! Here, the person misses the key word "Automatically" (in fact, with capital first letter!). And it is invalidating to recommend starting Apache service from the control panel ... as if the asker couldn't do it by himself!! And I am even *more* amazed that this reply received so many votes!!!  
So, besides this reply being out of place it is also bad.

Comment: -> Config (upper right button) -> Autostart modules -> select Apache (and whatever other) checkbox. Now, it is a working reply.

Comment: If checkboxe are still uncheckable try my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960296/how-to-start-apache-and-mysql-automatically-when-windows-8-comes-up/45413206#45413206

Comment: @Apostolos what you are suggesting says "Selected modules will be started on the next launch of the control panel" which I guess isn't what OP wants.

Answer (score 73):

Go to the *Config* button (upper right) and select the *Autostart* for Apache:

[image: Config button]

[image: Autostart modules]

To start XAMPP at startup in Windows, paste a shortcut of the XAMPP control panel in this folder:

> C:\Users\ **USERNAME** \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

or

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

Comment: selecting autostart starts the selected modules ("apache" and "mysql"  here as i have selected these two modules) but not the 'xampp control panel' itself. we need to start the contol panel manually (i am not sure on other version but on  'xampp contol panel v3.2.1 '). To start the control panel itself with the services/modules on the system start up, first we need to run control panel as administrator. then select the module as 'service' in the left of the control panel.

Comment: Thank you...would have never known that...I've been using xampp all this time too!

Comment: Thanks, this was what we needed 

Answer (score 15):

#### Apache

1. Run `cmd` as administrator
2. Go to the Apache bin directory, for example, `C:\xampp\apache\bin`
3. Run: `httpd.exe -k install` [more information](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#winsvc)
4. Restart the computer, or run the service manually (from *services.msc*)

#### MySQL

1. Run `cmd` as administrator
2. Go to the MySQL bin directory, for example, `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`
3. Run: `mysqld.exe --install` [more information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-start-service.html)
4. Restart the computer, or run the service manually (from *services.msc*)

Comment: Perfect answer.  Thanks.  Just make sure the services are stopped in XAMPP before doing the above items.

Comment: Ended up here for a general search on install Apache service to start at windows boot (not XAMPP specific). I ran "httpd.exe -k install" in a normal cmd (not as administrator), and it worked, but then the serivce doesn't start at boot even if it's set to start automatically. So for me the "Run cmd as administrator" did the trick !

Comment: I can verify this works. No need to login user, both apache and mysql already running once the system complete boot up (ie show the login menu). Thanks!

Comment: this should be accepted answer, as well deserves max upvotes.

Comment: For some reason the intl extension is not being loaded when running apache as a services this way.

Answer (score 9):

1. <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type *services.msc*
3. Search for your WAMP Apache and go to property and select *Auto*.
4. Restart your computer.

As a service

You can set this one by:

Going first to your installation directory (in my case it’s `c:\xampplite`). It could be somewhere else depending on your installation. Have also my full version in `c:\x2\xampp`.
Once your in the installation directory, find `xampp-control.exe` and click/double-click to launch it.

You should first stop all running instances of your `apache2` and `mysqld`/`mysql` processes to do this.

Click the checkmark next to Apache and MySQL with the header name service.
It will warn you that it’s installing as a service which of course is what we like it to do. Click <kbd>Yes</kbd>.

Also do step 5 with MySQL. We’re almost done.

Click *Start* → *Run*

Type *services.msc* (it can also be done in the control panel under administrative tools which is a way lot of click than this one). Find the Apache 2 and MySQL services.

Double click each one and set the startup type to Automatic (you will be presented with three options: *Automatic*, *Manual*, and *Disabled*):

- **Automatic** – will start it automatically at startup
- **Manual** – users will have to start it up manually i.e. by issuing a command like `net start apache2`
- **Disabled** – will disable it.

**Be warned though that any change in the services just like the registry can cause your system to stall.**

Click the start button to manually start it (just for the session though). At the next restart it’ll be automated.

Do the same with MySQL.

As a startup program

Find xampp_start.exe from your installation directory.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it or right-click the file and hit copy.

Go to **C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Start Menu\Programs\Startup** and right click on it and hit *Paste Shortcut*.

When you restart it’ll be starting also and you’ll see something like this:

You can stop it by issuing the `xampp_stop.exe` command in your installation directory.

**Also** worth mentioning is that if you right click again on the shortcut and hit properties, try to change the run option to minimized. This way the shortcut will be on your taskbar once started.

Comment: This is the best and most thorough answer

Answer (score 8):

One of the latest XAMPP releases (XAMPP for Windows v5.6.11 (PHP 5.6.11) for sure, probably some earlier versions too) does not have the Control Panel with the "Svc" checkbox that allows to install Apache and MySQL as a service.

Go to your XAMPP/Apache directory instead (typically `C:/xampp/apache`) and *run apache_installservice.bat* as an administrator. There is also *apache_uninstallservice.bat* for uninstall.

To run MySQL as a service. Do it the same way - the location is `xampp/mysql` and batch files are: *mysql_installservice.bat* for service installation and *mysql_uninstallservice.bat* for removing the MySQL service.

You can check if they were installed or not by going to services manager window (press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type: *services.msc*) and check if you have Apache service (I had Apache2.4) running and set to startup automatically. The MySQL service name is just: *mysql*.

Answer (score 3):

You could copy the XAMPP shortcut into "Local Disk C /users/YourUserName/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Start-up"...

This will make the control panel start up with the computer. Then if you were to select the configuration in the top right hand corner of the control panel you can make Apache and MySQL auto start... This is a quite long-winded get around, but it works for Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Find/search for file "xampp-control.ini" where you installed XAMPP server (e.g., `D:\Server` or `C:\xampp`).

Then edit in n the [Autostart] section:

```
Apache=1
MySQL=1
FileZilla=0
Mercury=0
Tomcat=0
```

Where 1 = true and 0 = false

That's so simple.

Comment: The only thing this does is make Apache and MySQL automatically start when the XAMPP Control Panel is started, whereas the OP wanted to have Apache and MySQL autostart when the system starts up.

Answer (score 2):

Copy `xampp_start.exe` from your XAMPP install directory to `C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Replace `YOUR USERNAME` with your username.

Comment: The Question is about Windows-StartUp (not User-StartUp).

Answer (score 2):

If on your system **User Control Account** is *Off* then you can run the XAMPP as **Administrator** and check the boxes for run as service.

And if on your system **User Control Account** is *On* then it may not work. You have go to *Configuration files* and manually install as a service or run *apache_installservice.bat* for Apache and *mysql_installservice.bat* for MySQL at the path

> 1. C:\xampp\apache
> 2. C:\xampp\mysql

if path is the default path.

Answer (score 0):

#### Open:

C/users/YourUserName/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Start-up

#### If there is a problem finding the above directory:***

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and write ***shell:startup***. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will move you to the directory.

#### Drag and drop the XAMPP control panel to the above directory

It will open XAMPP automatically.

If you want to auto start Apache and MySQL, click on **config** in XAMPP and check the Apache and XAMPP items (if unchecked) and save it. It will start it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via cmd.

#### For Apache

Open cmd in administrator mode. Change directory to *C:/xampp/apache/bin*. Run the command as `httpd.exe -k install`.
Your Apache server service will be installed. You can start it from services.

#### For MySQL

Change directory to *C:/xampp/mysql/bin*. Run the command as `mysqld --install`. Your MySQL service will be installed. You can start it from services.

Note: Make sure the selected Apache and MySQL services are set to start automatically.

You're done. There isn't any need to launch the XAMPP control panel

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've tried using the Xampp Control Panel and choosing from the Config menu to start MySQL did not work. Instead go to C:\xampp\mysql and run a file entitled mysql_installservice and MySQL will automatically run as a Windows service.