# How to start xampp v3.2.1 starts automatically in windows startup?

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

Hi all I am using xampp v3.2.1 in windows 7. I want to start it automatically as windows start, but not able to do it.

I tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033083/xampp-start-automatically-on-windows7-startup) but not find anything in services.

I have installed xampp in **D drive** is this the reason why apache and mysql is not showed in services when open the **services.msc** from run.

I have tried it from the xampp control panel from the **config button** I check the checkbox to autostart but it start the services when I start the xampp control panel, not when system start.

So how can I do this, is there any way to do this. Please let me know.

And I also want to do the same thing in windows server 2008 however right now it is installed it in the ** C Drive** of the server but i want to install it on the **D drive** on server also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using xampp v.3.2.1 with windows 7. I have installed it on my C drive and I can see Apache and mysql in services.msc and both appear with auto start, maybe you should try to install in C drive.

Look at this response, It can be helpful to you: [How to start Apache and MySQL Automatically when Windows 8 comes up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960296/how-to-start-apache-and-mysql-automatically-when-windows-8-comes-up)

Comment: I know that if I can install it on C drive it will show in services.msc but I want to install it on D drive only, because there are many reason not to install on C drive. so if you have any solution for that than please tell me.

Comment: Have you tried to start Run dialog and type shell:startup? Then open that folder and create a shortcut to xampp-control.exe, What's the result?

Comment: Nothing happen, I already tried that before. not found the services in startups.

Comment: I can't think of anything else you can try, sorry. I don't know why you don't want to use C drive, maybe that is the only solution for autorun. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Start the control panel using "Run as administrator", then you can install apache, Mysql as a service.