# How does my executable JavaFX file connect to a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql

I've recently finished working on my first JavaFX app.
It connects with a MySQL database that is set up on a local server.
Before using the application I need to start the servers running using Xampp.
Now I want to finally pack my app into an .exe file and use it.
I'm a complete newbie when it comes to the servers and databases. My question is - what do I do to make my app connect with the database itself once the user opens it?
Do I need to switch from a local host server to a remote server that will not require starting it each time?

My JavaFX app connects with MySQL using JDBC.

```java
private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Finance?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    private static String login = "root";
    private static String password = "";

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
        return connection;
    }
```

Comment: In the main, where is the entry point of your app, connect to the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test your connection with a method like this:

```
public boolean canConnect() {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
        //executed only if no errors are thrown
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //can't connect
        return false;
    } finally {
        //close connection if it was successful
        try {
            if (con!=null) con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

by calling it in your **main** method, or in your first **stage** like this:

```
if (!canConnect()) {
    //notify the user
    //start xampp or check connection to local server
} //else proceed
```

If you want to deploy your application with Xampp, you need to make Xampp to autostart when pc boots up, so the user don't have to start it manually in each boot.
If you are wondering how to auto-start your MySQL service in Xampp, you can [find it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960296/how-to-start-apache-and-mysql-automatically-when-windows-8-comes-up)

Comment: Okay, fair enough! But what if I wanted to run this app on the computer that doesn't have Xampp?

Comment: @lvndsky in that case you need an in-memory database like **H2**, or a remote server.